# What is the difference between the two summation functions in Common Lisp, thanks

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, elisp

Both code examples are the for the summation formula:
[image: Code examples are for the summation formula]

Code example 1

```
(defund sigma (func n)
        (cond ((= n 1)(funcall func 1)
        (t (+ (sigma func(1- n))
           (funcal func n))))))
```

Code example 2

```
(defund sigma(n)
        (cond ((= n 1)1)
        (t (+ n(sigma func(1- n))))
```

Comment: Neither of these functions compute what you say they do. The second function has a reference to an undefined variable, `func`. Your indentation is hopeless and makes the code extremely difficult to read. You do not specify which language this is. I don’t know what `defund` is supposed to be. I strongly recommend that you fix this question if you want someone to answer it.

Comment: `defund` isn't a standard operator in Common Lisp; can you provide a citation of what library that is from, or add some documentation about it to your question?

Comment: Your second `defund` doesn't seem to be taking `func` as an argument, only `n`. Yet it is referencing `func` and appears to be passing it to itself. This may be some feature of the mysterious `defund`; under the regular `defun`, this would be erroneous: the function `sigma` would only be callable with exactly  one argument.

Answer (score 4):

> Both code examples are the for the summation formula

No they do not.  While the second sums the numbers, the first calls a function with the number as argument and sums the result. 
It would have `f(i)` instead of just `i` after the sigma in the mathematical notation. In higher order function lingo it is a term function. Here are some examples using `10`:

```
(sigma (lambda (v) 1) 10) ; ==> 10 in CL I'd use (sigma (constantly 1) 10)
(sigma #'1+ 10)           ; ==> 65
(sigma #'identity 10)     ; ==> 55
```

The second would only produce the third example:

```
(sigma 10) ; ==> 55
```

PS: Your functions have syntax errors and typos I have just ignored. You'lll need to fix these before it works. The hardest one is perhaps the missing ending parenthesis in the first `cond` term making the `cond` only have one term and the second function also passing `func`, which doesn't make sense since its version only takes one argument.